# How to trigger "Perform GC" programmatically in JMX

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

how can i trigger the "Perform GC" programmatically after the reaching to certain heap memory.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AsV.png)

Comment: Why have you tagged this with *python* **and** *perl* **and** *java*? Those are *very* different languages. Further, what do you mean by "Perform GC"? Why do you think you can manage memory in an environment with automatic memory management?

Comment: I agree, you should tags like Perl and Python, because they have nothing to do with JVM GC. Experienced users will gladly downvote you. (Note, that's not my downvote).

Comment: *Why* do you want to call GC yourself? Let Java manage its memory as it was designed to. If you want to manage your own memory, allocate off-heap or use a different language.

Comment: As my application is getting hanged/crashed after reaching to some limit. For Example if i have set the memory size to 512mb then it is getting crashed at 300mb. so i was planning to call the "Perform GC" programmatically when it reaches 300mb.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force and immediate collection though as the garbage collector is non-deterministic. Your best bet is `System.gc()` call that recommends GC to start.

You should also tweak JVM options Properties -> run -> VM options. Read this article for details. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150